# Use SQL expression as calculated field in Amazon Quicksights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to integrated a simple SQL expression in Amazon Quicksights, but every time I use the calculated field I get a error stating that the methods used are not valid.

Amazon Quicksight does not let me use aggregate functions:

ROUND((**SUM**(CASE WHEN dyn_boolean THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / **COUNT**(session_unique), 2)

I know that I can change the **CASE** into a **ifelse**, but that does not solve the entire problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full power of SQL while preparing data, use custom SQL option during creation of data set.

'New Data set' -> 'FROM EXISTING DATA SOURCES' ->'Create Data Set'->'Edit and Preview Data'-> 'Switch to custom SQL tool'

[image: Data preparation using custom SQL]

You can write custome SQL of your choice .